# How to get values from specific web page that is open on firefox browser

Tags: vba

I am using the AppActivate to focus on a web page that is already open on Firefox (do not want to open a new tab or another instance of Firefox). From this tab I would like to copy specific values by the `getElementById` and paste on a new sheet to send by email.
Could someone please help? I tried different ways but none worked until now.

```
Sub startFirefox()
    Dim appfile As String
    Dim fftask As Double

    appfile = "Firefox"
    On Error Resume Next
    AppActivate "Firefox"
        If Err <> 0 Then
            Err = 0
            fftask = Shell(appfile, 1)
            If Err <> 0 Then MsgBox "Cannot start FF" 'if firefox is not open going to open a new instance
        End If

    '2nd part that i need to get the values from web page
    Dim varA, Url As String
    Url = "example"
    Dim Site As Object
    Set Site = CreateObject("firefox.application")

    Dim oHTMLDoc As Object
    Set oHTMLDoc = Site.Document
    varA = oHTMLDoc.getElementById("X5").Value

    MsgBox varA  'here is not showing any value. I put the msgbox just to see if is getting any value
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not simply automate with selenium basic and automate FF that way?

Comment: @Qharr, At the company we cannot use all apps that we want. We have an internal list of authorizade apps that can be installed on the machines.

Comment: Can you submit a request? Are you allowed to use python?

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as `Firefox.Application`. So it will never work.

Programmers use Internet Explorer - the programmable browser. So use `Set site = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`

`AppActivate` is not needed when using COM and it has a large set of rules preventing it working for programs (it's designed to PREVENT programs stealing focus).

Comment: Thanks @Noodles for the explanation.